# Using sbt-dynver with git submodules

Tags: scala, sbt

Have anyone managed to use the great [sbt-dynver](https://github.com/dwijnand/sbt-dynver) plugin with sbt subprojects ,  
 which also happen to be submodules in git?  
I would like the version for subprojects to be calculated from the submodule git repository,  
while the root project's version should be deducted from the main repo.

Comment: Have you tried anything?

Comment: @LeviRamsey yeah.. bascially when I create a "multiproject" build where each subroject is also a git submodule, I can see the correct subproject's version (the one taken from the submodule's repo) **only if I execute the sbt commands from the subproject directory**.
When I execute commands from the root project, it takes the version from the main git repo and wrongly sets it for all the subprojects.

Comment: `sbt-dynver` just executes some CLI git commands and then parses the output. If you can come up with git command(s) that return what you need, you can parse the output yourself in your sbt file without using `sbt-dynver`.

Comment: @VladimirKorenev , the choice of reimplementing the plugin or implementing the missing functionallity is always there, it ain't no answer. If on the contrary you claim that it **can't be done** with *sbt-dynver* at it is currently implemented in a proper way, it could be a reasonable answer.

Answer (score 0):

We have eventually ended up with the following configuration:

We have an sbt root project (which happen to be also a git project)  
and this project contains **no code**, and only acts as an **aggregator** for sbt subprojects.

The sbt subprojects (which also happen to be standalone git repos) contain all configuration needed to be independent standalone sbt projects (with their own build.sbt and plugins.sbt definitions).

Pros:

- Each subproject has it's own version.
- The CI system can concentrate on the subprojects without knowing anyhthing about the parent root project.
- We can open all those project at once with intellij from the root sbt project.

Cons:

- Can not aggregate mutual configurations for sbt subprojects in one place.
- The only value of the root project is in the ability it provides us opening all subprojects inside the same intellij instance.  
  The commits for the root project are pretty useless, so the "git multimodule" overhead ceremony is really something to consider twice.

Next step: We are considering to remove the **root project from git** and staying just with the subprojects as standalone git repos.  
Yes it will eliminate the possibility to clone "everything needed at once" and each team member will have to maintain the **root aggregator project** as a local directory, but on the other side maintaining a 'git with submodules' project requires continuous effort as well.